# In JS, is it allowed to declared the same name of functions with different number of parameters like Java?

Tags: javascript, function

Before I start writing this post, I already tried the codes below;

```
function foo(a){
    alert(a);}

function foo(a, b){
    alert(a + ' ' + b);}
```

And in a function which called when the page is loaded, I called the two functions as this: `foo(1); foo(1, 2);` Then I firstly got "1 undefined" and then "1 2".

What I expected first is that I might be able to declare the same name of functions with different parameters like Java; but I'm not sure I can. At least I'm sure that declaring `function foo(a, b){...}` and `function foo(b, c){...}` is prohibited.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript does not support function overloading

You can like this way simulate function  overloading in javascript

```
function mother_foo(a, b) {
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    foo(a)
  } else if (arguments.length == 2) {
   foo(a,b)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow like this.Because of this two function will be the window  Object attribute.

When brower read `function foo(a){}`,the foo will add to window Object.You can run `console.log(window.log)` to see the result.

Whe brower read `function foo(b, c)`，the provious will be overwrite，You can run `console.log(window.log)` to see the current result.